# Angular custom control contenteditable, how do I hook up ngModel?

Tags: angular

```html
<button (click)="onSaveChanges()">Save Changes</button>
<section>
  <news-column *ngFor="let column of news.columns">
    <news-header>
      <h2 contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
        {{ column.header }}
      </h2>
    </news-header>
    <news-content contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
      {{ column.content }}
    </news-content>
    <news-read-more contenteditable="true">
      {{ column.readmore.text }}
    </news-read-more>
    <news-photo contenteditable="true">{{ column.photo.url }} </news-photo>
  </news-column>
</section>
```

I'm allowing users to edit content using contenteditable.  Problem is that the data is bound to news.columns as shown above.  When user makes changes I can see them via this construct:

```
     ele.addEventListener("input", event => {
          let change = event.target as HTMLElement;
          console.log(change.innerText);
        });
```

But when looking at the news.column binding, the changes are not there.  The traditional approach is to add [ngModel] etc.  But ngModels only apply to input elements. Not any contenteditable element. I'd prefer the changes to happen in the binding, but as mentioned I can see the changes at the DOM layer.

Any suggestions on getting the bindind content to relfect the change e.g. each news.column should have the edited content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you need to do more implementation. contenteditable isn't an angular thing, it's an HTML attribute that specifies that the element is editable. I could be wrong but I don't think that has anything to do with angular's binding. I searched Angular.io and "contenteditable" comes up with zero hits in docs.

Fortunately there seem to be some examples of how to create a directive for this, and it seems many modules (angular-mentions) wrap that up for you.

Here's two examples I semi-randomly picked from searching for "contenteditable angular" on GitHub:

https://github.com/KostyaTretyak/ng-stack/tree/master/projects/contenteditable

https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/angular-contenteditable-accessor

If you look up some code, you find the same thing: create a directive that manages the content updates, e.g:

```
/*
 * This is a barebones contenteditable {@link ControlValueAccessor} allowing you to use
 * Angular forms with native contenteditable HTML. For security reasons you might want
 * to consider sanitizing pasted/dropped content before using it. Also make sure that
 * you do not set any dangerous content as control value yourself, because directive
 * just outputs control value as-is.
 */
@Directive({
    selector:
        '[contenteditable][formControlName], [contenteditable][formControl], [contenteditable][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => ContenteditableValueAccessor),
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
})
etc. etc.
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, you are right it had nothing to do with the binding because binding cannot happen on any other element than an input element (which uses [ngModel]).  I didn't know that until today when I tried to hook up ngModel to those controls shown above.

Comment: Hmm...binding happens on a lot of elements (for instance a radio button), you can two-way bind etc. by using the "banana in a box" format [(someevent)] and all that, and you can always implement binding on anything yourself. That said though, yeah you'll need to set up some code to make contenteditable an attribute directive.

Comment: Was able to come up with pretty cool debug directive.  https://dev.to/jwp/angular-debugger-directive-13ob  For problem above I discarded the content editable concept in favor of in place markdown editor.