# Add formControlName in a div with contenteditable

Tags: angular, richtextbox, angular-forms, form-control

I have a div with contenteditable="true" because i need a rich text component, and i tried a lot of libraries but nothing works, so i have my div editable but when i try to add the formControlName i got this error:

this is my HTML

```
<div formControlName="main_description" class="full" id="textBox" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

And this is the error

```
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'main_description'
at _throwError (forms.js:1734:1)
at setUpControl (forms.js:1508:1)
at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5255:1)
at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5837:1)
at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5782:1)
at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:1520:1)
at callHook (core.js:2539:1)
at callHooks (core.js:2506:1)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2457:1)
at selectIndexInternal (core.js:8401:1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular custom control contenteditable, how do I hook up ngModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608113/angular-custom-control-contenteditable-how-do-i-hook-up-ngmodel)

Comment: show us your whole html for the form please. Or add your own value accessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution!
I had to add an invisible input to assign the div data

here is: https://github.com/Avalojandro/Angular-RichText-PureJS

Answer (score 0):

Yes the control value accessor needs to be implemented, which is basically an interface angular provides to create custom form controls. The error you are getting is because the directive formControlName expects the element you are trying to bind to be a custom element which implements this interface.

Basically check the resources here: [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)

Also this should help you: [Implementing ControlValueAccessor](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/)